# Unity C# - Setting up a dictionary for Addressable in Coroutine. Values get corrupted

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm trying to save AssetReferences in a dictionary by using a Coroutine. I do this when the game launches. Since there are many references (~700 for now) to save and I don't want the intro video to be frozen while filling up the dictionary, I use yield to wait for half a second in the Coroutine after every 150 references are saved. The dictionary consists of string-class key-value pairs.

If the Coroutine yields, the values of the dictionary somehow gets corrupted. If I remove the yields from the Coroutine and let it fill the dictionary in one frame, everything works fine. Is this behavior expected?

The interesting thing is I use this dictionary for Addressables (AssetReference). If I play the game with "Fast Mode" the dictionary works fine with yields. If I play the game with "Packed Play Mode" and use yields, the dictionary gets corrupted, however everything works fine with no yields. I'm so confused.

NOTE: The values of the dictionary don't become null. They all exist, but Addressable cannot use those values to load assets. For example; LoadAssetAsync function works since the values are not null, however, the asset never loads, because the Completed handler of the AssetReference (AsyncOperationHandle) gets stuck at loading.

A part of the code:

```
        // 'References' is the dictionary
        // 'Characters' and 'Weapons' are just arrays storing a class, AssetReference
        // 'CharacterKeys' and 'WeaponKeys' are just arrays storing strings
 
        int counter = 0;
 
        if (Characters != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Characters.Length; ++i)
            {
                References.Add(CharacterKeys[i], Characters[i]);
 
                ++counter;
                if (counter > 150)
                {
                    counter = 0;
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
                }
            }
 
            Characters = null;
        }
 
        if (Weapons != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Weapons.Length; ++i)
            {
                References.Add(WeaponKeys[i], Weapons[i]);
 
                ++counter;
                if (counter > 150)
                {
                    counter = 0;
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
                }
            }
 
            Weapons = null;
        }
```

If I remove the yields from the Coroutine, everything starts working. The code down below works fine.

```
        // 'References' is the dictionary
        // 'Characters' and 'Weapons' are just arrays storing a class, AssetReference
        // 'CharacterKeys' and 'WeaponKeys' are just arrays storing strings
 
        int counter = 0;
 
        if (Characters != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Characters.Length; ++i)
            {
                References.Add(CharacterKeys[i], Characters[i]);
            }
 
            Characters = null;
        }
 
        if (Weapons != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Weapons.Length; ++i)
            {
                References.Add(WeaponKeys[i], Weapons[i]);
            }
 
            Weapons = null;
        }
```

This must be related to the "Packed Play Mode", because everything works in "Fast Mode" with or without yields. I guess, when the code reaches the package (Addressables), it should access the required AssetReference at once (in one frame)?

By the way, I don't forget to build Addressable before testing. It's not related to the building.

EDIT: I think, I have to emphasize that this is not about dictionaries and Corotuines. This is about reading AssetReference in a Coroutine. If the Coroutine yields at some point, the read AssetReference somehow gets corrupted and can't be used anymore. In my case, I save those AssetReference in a dictionary.

EDIT2: I also tested same logic with async-await functions, but it gave me the same result. This must be about delaying, dictionaries and Addressable.

Comment: @Tatranskymedved OP is speaking about a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) which doesn't run async actually.

Comment: @Tatranskymedved if it were related to IEnumerable, it wouldn't work in "Fast Mode" too in my opinion. I think, this is about Coroutines and Addressable Build.

Comment: You are right, ignore previous comment. Sorry for misleading.